# I am testing to capture the submit button value on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to capture the value of a submit button so I can submit the form based on this button being used.  The form name incidentform and the button name is updateincidentButton. Below is the code.

```
$(function(){
    $$("#incidentform").submit(function(e){
        var =$("#updateincidentButton").val();
        if(var==="Update incident"){
            alert(var);
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    })
})
```

Here is the basic html of the form

```
<form id="incidentform" action="/" method="get">
<input type="submit" class="button" id="updateincidentButton" name="updateincidentButton" value="Update Incident"/>

</form>
```

Comment: What is your question? Also is `$$("#incidentform")` a typo? Please add the relevant html

Comment: Yes the $$ is a typo from the copy and paste of the code.
I am sorry I meant to say they are the id name of the elements

Answer (score 3):

`var` is a reserved keyword in javascript. You can't use it as the name of a variable.
Change this:

```
var =$("#updateincidentButton").val();
```

to something like this:

```
var var1 = $("#updateincidentButton").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need two "$$".

Is the name "updateincidentButton" or the id? If it is currently the name, change it to the id:

```
<button id="incidentform">Click Me</button>
```

Same thing with the form. The hashtag that is passed into $ represents an id of an element.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to define your form somewhere...give it an ID:

```
<form id="aspnetForm">
....
<input type="button" id="updateincidentButton" value="Update incident"/>
</form>
```

Next, change your JavaScript:

```
$("#updateincidentButton").click(function(e){
    if ($(this).val() == "Update incident"){
        $("aspnetForm").submit();
        }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is submit the form using ajax.  I just want to test the button action. Is your code above going to work along doing that? Isn't the e.preventdefault() stopping the default action of the button click and not the default action of the form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `type` of the button is 'button'.

```
$(document).on('click', '#updateincidentButton', function () {
    var value = $('#updateincidentButton').val();
    if (value == 'Update incident') {
        alert(value);
    }
});
```

Then you won't even have to prevent default. Then submit form using AJAX. Posting to a URL dependent on the value of the button when clicked.